# Is this an idiomatic French equivalent of "I won't lose any sleep over it"?

Tags: expressions

> Mais cela ne me touche pas **au point de ne pas en dormir la nuit**.

Also, I wonder if this sentence is grammatically correct in the first place, with the subject "cela" not matching with the subject of *who cannot sleep*: me.

Comment: Ça ne va pas m'empêcher de dormir...

Comment: C'est plutôt une métaphore courante qu'une expression idiomatique car par exemple "Mais cela ne me touche pas au point de m'ôter le sommeil." est plus rare mais on comprend exactement la même chose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's perfectly correct, the word `cela` reffers to the cause (for example an accident or a conflict),

In my personal opinion, a better sentence would be :

> Mais cela ne me touche pas **au point de ne pas dormir la nuit.**

or

> Mais cela ne me touche pas **au point de m'empêcher de dormir durant la nuit.**